# Python: fastest way to extract sublist from a list of objects given an attribute

Tags: python, performance, list

Say I have this simple class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, number, name):
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
```

and a list of Foo instances:

```
l = [Foo(10, 'a'), Foo(9, 'a'), Foo(8, 'a'), Foo(7,'a'), Foo (5, 'b'), Foo (4, 'b') ,Foo (3, 'b')]
```

Say that the 'name' attribute can only be either 'a' or 'b'.

What is **the fastest way** to extract the sublist of all the objects whose 'name' is 'a' (or 'b')? Notice that this operation might be called several million times and this is why I want to optimize it as much as I can.

**Note** that the list is built in a way such that it will have all the elements 'grouped together' in the first or second half of the list. The list is symmetric and order by the decreasing attribute 'number'. 
**EDIT**: Not necessarily there is the same number of 'a' and 'b'.

---

How I do it:

In the beginning I was just doing a for loop:

```
sublist = []
for o in l:
  if o.name == 'a'
  sublist.append(o)
```

Then I tried with a list comprehension:

```
sublist = [o for o in l if o.name=='a']
```

But this seems to be approximately the same if not a bit slower.

Either way, neither of those exploits the assumption that all the attributes are already 'grouped together' in the original (sorted) list. It will keep looping even when it's no longer necessary. Speed is very important so I need it to be as performant as possible.

Comment: You cannot group all desired element without iterating over whole list. I can only suggest you using generator if it allowed.

Comment: If there are only 'a' and 'b' values, and 'a' is always comes first then you can use binary search to find the last 'a' element an use slice to get all 'a' elements. O(logN) to find the last 'a' element, but it is still O(N) to make a copy of the list

Comment: Are they in lexicographic order or just clumped? Can you optimize higher up? Before you build the list? This data structure is not ideal for this sort of thing.

Comment: Also, you said "speed is very important" but you did not say how large can your list be. If it is less than 10^5, then I am not sure if this is the right place to optimize the code

Comment: Well, I totally missed that there are the same number of 'a' and 'b' elements. Binary search is useless here then, as you can find the middle point in O(1) as suggested by Shaido

Comment: @soon unfortunately just now I was told that not necessarily are the same number. Will update the question

Comment: How large could your list be?

Comment: @soon let's say maybe at most few tens of thousands

Comment: Then naive approach (with loop) should take no more than 1 second. Are you sure this is the right place to optimize? Also, as I already said, if you want to make a copy of this list, it will still cost O(N) no matter how fast can you find the last 'a' element. I am preparing the full answer though.

Comment: @soon the point is that operation might be iterated for a few millions of times. Of course there are other points to optimize, I just want to make sure I am optimizing everything.

Comment: You mean, your function might be called for a few millions of times, right? Then, yes, you should optimize it. You just did not mention this in your question, that is why I started asking questions about the length of your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use binary search to find the middle point in O(logN):

```
In [19]: class Foo(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self, number, name):
    ...:         self.number = number
    ...:         self.name = name
    ...:         
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:         return 'Foo(number={self.number}, name={self.name})'.format(self=self)
    ...:     

In [20]: def binary_search(lst, predicate):
    ...:     """
    ...:     Finds the first element for which predicate(x) == True
    ...:     """
    ...:     lo, hi = 0, len(lst)
    ...:     while lo < hi:
    ...:         mid = (lo + hi) // 2
    ...:         if predicate(lst[mid]):
    ...:             hi = mid
    ...:         else:
    ...:             lo = mid + 1
    ...:     return lo
    ...: 

In [21]: l = [Foo(10, 'a'), Foo(9, 'a'), Foo(8, 'a'), Foo(7,'a'), Foo (5, 'b'), Foo (4, 'b'
    ...: ) ,Foo (3, 'b')]

In [22]: binary_search(l, lambda x: x.name == 'b')
Out[22]: 4

In [23]: l[:binary_search(l, lambda x: x.name == 'b')]
Out[23]: 
[Foo(number=10, name=a),
 Foo(number=9, name=a),
 Foo(number=8, name=a),
 Foo(number=7, name=a)]

In [24]: l[binary_search(l, lambda x: x.name == 'b'):]
Out[24]: [Foo(number=5, name=b), Foo(number=4, name=b), Foo(number=3, name=b)]
```

However, note, that:

1. Naive approach with O(N) complexity should take less than 1 sec to complete for 10<sup>4</sup> elements.
2. While making a copy you still need to iterate over the array which results in O(N)
3. If you are facing performance issues it is good idea to use profiler to find bottlenecks in your program. Iterating over 10<sup>4</sup> elements is usually not a bottleneck (except if you are iterating 10<sup>4</sup> times over 10<sup>4</sup> elements - which results in 10<sup>8</sup>). However, querying 10<sup>4</sup> from db may be a bottleneck as it also uses network, may query other items and so on. When in doubt - use profiler

Comment: Thanks, the binary search makes quite a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Just break out of the loop once you hit a non-match after matching

```
sublist = []
for o in l:
    if o.name == 'a'
        sublist.append(o)
    elif sublist:
        break
```

If you wanted to use generators, you could use the `itertools` functions

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

sublist = list(takewhile(lambda o: o.name == 'a', dropwhile(lambda o: o.name != 'a', l))
```

These both exploit the fact that the list is sorted and stop processing the list after the items stop matching.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `name` attribute can only be 'a' or 'b' which are ordered and you have the same number of 'a' and 'b', the simplest way would be to find the middle point and slice the list:

```
mid = int(len(aList)/2)
sublist = l[:mid]
```

The above will give you all 'a' while `l[mid:]` gives all 'b'.

---

**Edit:** Since the question was changed and it's no longer true that the number of elements of 'a' and 'b' are the same the above answer does not work anymore.

Depending on the length of the list, my guess would be that either binary search (for longer lists) or breaking out of the loop as Brendan suggested (for shorter ones) would be the fastest approach.

Comment: Exactly what I just realized myself! Writing it down just helped and I was about to update when you posted your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I also just found out that might not always be the same so that cannot work. Upvoted anyway since it was spot on with my original answer. Have to work out the non-symmetric case though.